# Android starts to kill apps only when available memory is lower than threshold?

Tags: android

As we know, when the memory becomes low, Android may start to kill some background apps to free memory. E.g. Nexus 7, this low-memory threshold is 64MB.

However, I observed that, even the available memory was enough (e.g. 150MB) to launch a new app (e.g. AngryBirds with 30MB), still the Android might kill some background apps. Is this possible?

If so, then what are the other "conditions" in which the Android "killer" would be also invoked?

Comment: General rule is that if your activity isn't the foreground activity, it can be cleaned at any time.  If you're writing an app you have to assume this.  Unless you're making a complex system off of android where you control the hardware and can customize the OS I wouldn't worry about when it could happen, but programming to minimize the effect when it does.

Comment: Your app shouldn't need to be concerned with when Android may kill it. Why do you need to know the conditions exactly?

Comment: Moreover, what makes you think that those conditions are the same on all devices? If it is not part of the Android SDK, device manufacturers have free reign to change what they want, so long as they do not break compatibility. Plus, the conditions may well have changed over the years in different Android OS versions.